# Writing spinor bilinear explicitly in terms of polar and axial four vectors

Tags: fermions, dirac-equation, spinors

I need help writing the fermion bilinear $$\bar{u}_s(\mathbf{p},m) \gamma^\mu\gamma_5 u_{s'}(\mathbf{p},m) = ?$$ which transforms like an axial vector, in terms of polar and axial four-vectors such as $p^\mu$ and $S^\mu$.  The spinors are defined by fixed axis quantization, with projections $s, s'=\pm 1/2$. The momenta and masses are equal.

I am able to successfully derive $$\bar{u}_s(\mathbf{p},m) \gamma^\mu u_{s'}(\mathbf{p},m) = 2 p^\mu \delta_{ss'}$$ by considering the cases $\mu=0$ and $\mu=\{1,2,3\}$ separately, and explicitly expanding the $u$ spinors.  However, the case with the $\gamma_5$ leads to combinations that are unfamiliar to me.

Is there an easy way to derive this? and how so?  My guess is that $\bar{u}_s(\mathbf{p},m) \gamma^\mu\gamma_5 u_{s'}(\mathbf{p},m) \propto S^\mu$, but I would like to derive it.

Comment: Fierzing does not help?

Comment: @AMS Fierz identities I am familiar with involve product of *two* bilinears.  The case at hand is only one bilinear.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: The result you derived in the first place, i guess it is the consequence of Fierzing.